# Dynamically "hide" OData entity properties/ values based upon user permissions

Tags: c#, odata

I see a bunch of similarly worded questions, but the ones that actually seem similar to what I'm asking don't have usable answers, so I'm going to try here.

We have a business requirement that our online reports that are accessible via OData will restrict certain properties/ columns visibility based upon a user's permissions. I'll illustrate an example:

Joe Salesman can look at a report for **Widget Sales**, but if he doesn't have the *Product Manager* role, he shouldn't be able to see the **Cost** value for any particular widget sale. If he doesn't have the *Sales Manager* role, he shouldn't be able to see the **Representative** or **Commission** values.

On the front-end, this is relatively easy to manage by looking at the claims available for the user, but we really need to ensure that calling the OData endpoint doesn't bring back information that Joe Salesman isn't supposed to have access to.

When creating the EDM model, you can explicitly ignore certain properties, but they are ignored by everyone and cannot be evaluated in the session.

Is there a way to do this that is not completely unmaintainable code sorcery?